# Unable to add Dynamics 365 as Source and Data verse as Destination in Azure Data Factory, the datasets are disabled unable to choose them

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataverse

Unable to add Dynamics 365 as Source and Common Data Service (Data verse) as Destination in Azure Data Factory. Please refer screenshot below, the datasets are disabled unable to choose them.

Is there any configuration missed out.

Requriment is pushing Dynamic 365 data to Data verse web API using Azure Data Factory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the icons are gray, it means that they are not supported in Data Flow. Please ref the connector overview.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any configuration you missed out. This is because Data Flow doesn't support them as source/sink. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#supported-sinks to get the supported connectors.